# MVC 5 Logout timeout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication, logout

Users are asked to login every 20 min or so.

One of those situations where don't know where to look. I'm using C# MVC 5 IdentityFramework 1.0.0

I want to make timeout time to 4 hours.

Till now I have tried in web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <sessionState timeout="2880"></sessionState>
      <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
  </authentication>
</system.web>
```

and in Startup.Auth.sc:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(4),
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Never,
            CookieHttpOnly = false,
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        });
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT - SOLUTION**

The solution is to put machineKey in web.config under system.web. Key generator can be found http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey

I have also migrated to Identity 2.0 and kept these settings. Migrated using this blog as a guid: http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/07/13/ASPNET-Identity-20-Extending-Identity-Models-and-Using-Integer-Keys-Instead-of-Strings.aspx

Comment: What is the Problem u r facing actually?

Comment: Users are asked to login every 20 min or so.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem? I'm interested in the solution

Comment: Question updated with a solution. Thanks for clews to solution

Comment: worked as said :)

Comment: You can also [add your solution as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it as correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Does it happen even if you run the site locally? Take a look at [this blog post](http://blog.falafel.com/asp-net-forms-authentication-times-out-on-a-shared-host/) describing a similar case.

The point from the blog post being:

> ...remember that Forms Authentication uses the computer’s machineKey
>   to encrypt the Forms Authentication cookie. "Could the machine key be
>   changing over time on my shared hosting server?", I wondered.
>
> Before emailing them to ask, I looked at the documentation on MSDN for
>   machineKey and discovered that there is an AutoGenerate mode that can
>   be set to regenerate a new machineKey each time the host process for a
>   web application starts up…after **20 minutes** of inactivity! Ah ha!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not have any background ajax activity as it affects session   (SlidingExpiration is true by default). Also you have to manually delete old cookies after   changing ExpireTimeStamp from default 14 days to smaller value.

Comment: I don't think so. I have few Ajax requests, but just for forms here and there. Is it smarther then to switch to session or database instead of cooky?